# Alternatives to "He is of the opinion"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Are there alternatives to "is of the opinion ..." in the following sentence?

> **He is of the opinion** that there is a something upon which we depend.

Because I am not an English native speaker, the expressions like "is of + noun" are ambiguous a little bit.

Comment: 'Be of the opinion that' is virtually a fixed idiom - and you won't find many other expressions 'be of the ____ (that)'. 'He is of the opinion that' means virtually the same as 'he believes that', 'he thinks that' (or the old-fashioned or even archaic 'he holds that').

Comment: Perhaps just worth mentioning that it used to be _he is of opinion that_.

Comment: Errr.... what's wrong with ***he thinks***? @Edwin: There's also [he is of a mind to...](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he+is+of+a+mind+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom "is of the opinion that" is fairly well entrenched. Using it would not be ambiguous.

That said, I believe it's wordy.

Indeed, I'm of the opinion that it would better to simply say, "he thinks that", "he believes that" or "his opinion is". I think that works better. It is also my opinion that wordiness is unnecessary. I believe it's better to avoid the passive.

See what I did there?

Answer (score 0):

> He is of the opinion that there is a something upon which we depend.

***In his opinion*** there is something upon which we depend.

"***In my opinion***" has pretty [widespread usage.](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/in_my_opinion.html)

This previous discussion covers the topic of ***"in my opinion"***, and may be of interest to you.
["I think ..." or "In my opinion..." or "From my point of view..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47298/i-think-or-in-my-opinion-or-from-my-point-of-view)