# Don’t understand “is of the...“

Tags: prepositions

Non-native speaker here, can’t understand the nuance of this sentence:

“Fully aware as **he is of the social unimportance of his creative activity**, he looks upon it as a way of working out his own development”

Here is what I think, probably wrong, need guidance:

He’s full aware that his creative activity does not have any social importance, (doesn’t affect society in any important way), he simply uses it for self development

I’m so confused what is **“as he is of”** mean?

Similar post: [Alternatives to "He is of the opinion"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127095/alternatives-to-he-is-of-the-opinion?newreg=5a77420cbf8640c48674b58a0ed6461e)

Comment: Your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, Victor's interpretation is correct but the passage is a long way from being a good example of clear, simple English. I prefer Victor's version.

Comment: Compare 'Ignorant as they are of the laws of the land, they will soon end up in jail' and 'Scared as he is of the dark, he likes to have a table light on when he is going to sleep.' It's almost a rearranged version of  'As they are ignorant of the laws of the land, they will soon end up in jail' etc, paraphrase 'Being ignorant of the laws of the land, they will soon end up in jail' etc.  Paraphrasing your sentence: Being fully aware, in the way that he is, of the social unimportance of his creative activity, ...'.  So [as he is of] is an infelicitous bracketing; 'Fully aware [as he is] of ...'

Comment: The sentence "Fully aware as he is of . . .," sounds a bit stiff and formal to me. I'm more comfortable in saying "He is fully aware of . . . but he nonetheless looks upon it as a way of working out his own personal development." Simpler yet would be to have two separate sentences: "He is fully aware . . .. He looks upon it . . .." The word "however" could also be used to good effect: "He is fully aware . . .. However, he looks upon it as . . .."

Comment: The sentence "Fully aware as he is of . . .," sounds a bit stiff and formal to me. I'm more comfortable in saying "He is fully aware . . .. However, he looks upon it as . . .." The words "but nonetheless" could be substituted for however: "He is fully aware . . ., but nonetheless . . .." Simpler yet is to have two separate sentences with no connecting words: "He is fully aware . . .." and "He looks upon it . . .." There are plenty of available options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're parsing it incorrectly.

> Fully aware [as he is] [of the social unimportance of his creative
> activity], he looks upon it as a way of working out his own
> development

He is "aware" of the "social unimportance".  The prepositional phrase beginning with "of" modifies "aware".

"As he is" also modifies "aware", independently of the "of" phrase, and is basically a "parenthetical".  One can get into arguments about whether "as" is an adverb or a conjunction or a preposition.  I'd argue for preposition, but that would likely get some folks here Pist.

Comment: “Parsing correctly” is the key. I guess more experience with the English language will help. Also I wish they could use commas to delimit the “parenthetical ideas”

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.

**Let me continue with another example:**

(1) Experienced in the use of English, I perceive this as a difficult question.

(2) Experienced as I am in the use of English, I perceive this as a difficult question.

(3) Experienced as I am in the use of English, I perceive this as an intriguing question.

(1) is a plain statement.

(2) uses *as I am* to imply that I find the question difficult, despite my experience.

(3) uses *as I am* to imply that I find the question intriguing, because of my experience (or even despite it).

This example suggests that the phrase *as I am* introduces an implication that depends on context or content. The implication is that there is a causal or similar conceptual connection between my experience and my perception of the question. There is some sort of balance to be made between *despite* and *because of*.

**In your case:**

(A) Fully aware of, ... he looks ...

(B) Fully aware of as he is ... he looks ...

(A) is the plain statement.

(B) may imply that despite (or because of) his awareness, he looks ...