# What's the difference between "to my mind", "in my opinion" and "in my view"?

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between "to my mind", "in my opinion" and "in my view"?

In [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+my+mind), "to my mind" is defined in all three cited dictionaries as "in my opinion" without offering any more explanation. On the other hand, the same dictionary defines "in my opinion" as "[as I see it](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/In+My+Opinion)"

Is one more common in a specific context/instance? Is one used more commonly generally? Is there a difference between its use in BrE and AmE? Is one use more formal/dated than the other?

According to Cambridge Dictionary,when we are expressing our beliefs or opinions, we use "in my opinion" or (the third candidate) "in my view".

They are technically synonymous, but in common speech, is there a difference?

Comment: **IMHO** they're much of a muchness.

Comment: @NigelJ For sure I did, that's the reason why I'm asking :p Cuz they are really similar and I want to differentiate them.

Comment: @Frenchlearningenglish While you have no answers, please just make a coherent single post. You don't need to put "edit" and list each addition separately. The edit history exists for that. Just put everything in a way which reads well. [When you have answers, large changes are frowned upon.]

Comment: @Frenchlearningenglish - Your question has been reopened.

Comment: Americans, in my experience, make a lot of use of "standpoint" in this context - "Looked at from my standpoint...". "Standpoint" is not so much used in Britain, where "my point of view" is a more popular idiom.

Comment: @WS2 - While I have heard "from my standpoint", *from where I stand* is more common, I think, or "in my view" and *from/in my point of view*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Hello :) Since I'm new on the forum, I'm not quite clear about the rules... There was one user who told me to write edits about what I've found out (I could have misunderstood btw...). Could you tell me what I should do with the answers I got? Thank you it would be well appreciated :)

Comment: So far, you haven't had any answers, only comments on the question. If they've helped, great. If not, then someone might actually provide an answer -- you'll get an inbox notification when that happens. Answers will appear under the line drawn below.

Comment: To my mind is a spoken phrase. Not used in formal writing.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that **in my opinion** allows a spoken emphasis to be placed either on  **my** or on **opinion**.

The other two expressions are not so general. They allow the word **my** to be emphasized, but an emphasis on **mind** or **view** would sound odd.

Answer (score 0):

***"in my view"*** and "in my opinion" are substantially the same and both work well for formal texts. [as substitutes for, or as in reference to a first-person point of view: In the view of this author, In the opinion of this author,for example.]

"to my mind" is a spoken phrase and ***would not be used in formal writing.***

I see no useful way to prove this.

Answer (score -1):

[I did a search using Google's Ngram Viewer to see how common those three phrases are in written sources.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=To%20my%20mind%2CIn%20my%20opinion%2CIn%20my%20view&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTo%20my%20mind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIn%20my%20opinion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIn%20my%20view%3B%2Cc0)

As you can see, *in my opinion* has been the most popular phrase throughout the past two centuries.  *In my view* has been catching up lately, but in my own personal experience (AmE) I have not heard it used very often.  I would personally always choose *in my opinion.*

As for *to my mind* I could not find a SINGLE instance of that phrased used in the way you describe.  Every instance cited in the ngram is actually used in a totally different way.  For example:

> [...the terms of which made it clear to my mind that he had not taken No for an answer...](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=YVe7AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT188&dq=I%20had%20to%20make%20it%20clear%20to%20my%20mind%20that&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkndvA78HXAhXGEbwKHeRWB1AQ6AEINjAC#v=onepage&q=I%20had%20to%20make%20it%20clear%20to%20my%20mind%20that&f=false)

I would wager the reason the definitions you found are so poor because it is a very uncommon phrase.

As for the difference between *in my opinion* and *in my view* I would agree with Global Charm.  *In my opinion* allows one to stress the *my* to emphasize what your opinion is in contrast to someone else's opinion.  Or you can stress the *opinion* to stress that this is just an opinion and not a fact. *In my view* only allows for the emphasis being placed on *my.*

In addition, a popular phrase used across various forms of media is IMHO (in my humble opinion).  This phrase has picked up a bit of a snarky, rude connotation in some cases.  [You can read more about that here on another question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/is-imho-a-rude-thing-to-say-or-type) So that can add an additional subtle layer of feeling when you use that phrase on the internet or with younger people.

**To keep it short and sweet: generally speaking, I personally see *in my opinion* and *in my view* as synonyms. But as previously stated, *in my opinion* is more common.**

If you want to do more research, many others have already asked this question across various websites.  Perhaps you would be interesting in reading them.

[In my view, in my opinion, in my point of view (wordreference.com)](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-my-view-in-my-opinion-in-my-point-of-view.2836237/)

[In my opinion, From my point of view, In my mind (wordreference.com)](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-my-opinion-from-my-point-of-view-in-my-mind.1464700/)

[“I think …” or “In my opinion…” or “From my point of view…” (ELU Stack Exchange)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47298/i-think-or-in-my-opinion-or-from-my-point-of-view)

['According To Me' Or 'In My Point Of View' (englishforums.com)](https://www.englishforums.com/English/AccordingPointView/drrhp/post.htm)

Answer (score -2):

both phrases in common speech are of a posture and are an interjection to a former context.

so i take its about position and knowledge.

"to my mind" is to sensitively state your comment with knowledge of invisible factors that is always occuring.

"in my view" is to state your school of thought upon the matter of discussion that has already been packaged

critical discussions work in phases in both profession and layman discussions.

the discussion in the legislative blueprint of a bank will be far different to the discussion of a bank that has been fully operating for some time, that said...the players involved will take different stances of remarks in according of their relevant respect,experience and position to submit their word.